# grunt watch image folder

Tags: macos, terminal, gruntjs

I try first time grunt.

I make an CSS Sprite with grunt-spritesheet and it works great.

Now I´d like do something more: When I add/remove image(s) in src folder, the sprite task sholud run automatically. I try this, but it doesn't work:

### Gruntfile.js

```
    module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Load the plugin(s)
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-spritesheet');
    
    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        
        /* Beginn tasks */
        
        watch: {
            files: ['src/**/*.png'],                
            tasks: ['spritesheet']
        },
                
        spritesheet: {
            generate: {
            
                // An array of filename / source images array pairs. The basename of the sprite file
                // is also prefixed to the CSS classes.
                sprites: {
                "images/sprite.png": ['src/**/*.png'], /* img src folder */
                
                },
                
                // The destination for the build stylesheet
                sheet: "css/sptite.css",
                
                // A mustache template used to render your sprites in a css file. (Optional)
                templateUrl: "template.mustache",
                
                // Optionally pass additional options to spritesmith
                // https://github.com/Ensighten/grunt-spritesmith
                spritesmithOptions: {
                padding: 2,
                algorithm: 'binary-tree'
                }
            }
        }
        
        /* End tasks */
        
    });
        
    // Default task(s)
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
    
};
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "Sprites",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.4",
    "grunt-spritesheet": "^0.1.4",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1"
  }
}
```

### Terminal

I run `grunt`

### Folder

[image]

### **Add file source `template.mustache`

```
{{#std}}
.{{&name}} {
    background-image: url({{&sprite}});
    width: {{width}}px;
    height: {{height}}px;
    background-position: -{{x}}px -{{y}}px;
}
{{/std}}



/**
 * Retina Display Media Query
 * http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/ 
 *
 */
 
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) { 

    {{#dbl}}
    .{{&name}} {
        background-image: url({{&sprite}});
        width: {{width}}px;
        height: {{height}}px;
        background-position: -{{x}}px -{{y}}px;
        background-size: {{spriteWidth}}px {{spriteHeight}}px;
    }
    {{/dbl}}
}
```

Thanks for your help
Ogni

Comment: I tried your Gruntfile (but removed the `template.mustache` part, since you didn't provide contents of that file—could you please provide it?), and for me it works perfectly, see this output I get: https://gist.github.com/kosmotaur/bb69e7a20911081bdfbb

Can you please say for which operations it doesn't work? For adding/deleting/renaming? All of them?
What OS do you run?
How are you running Grunt?

Comment: Hi @Kosmotaur: Thanks for your help an logfile. I add source of "template.mustache". I try it without this file but nothing happens (Waiting ...). I´m using Mac OS X 10.8.5 and run Terminal. Please can you share me your working  Gruntfile.js, too?

Comment: Hello :) here's my `Gruntfile.js`: https://gist.github.com/kosmotaur/73675b0a52b6c4f8255d

I am on a Mac as well, OSX 10.9.2. My Node version is v0.10.25

Comment: I've tried with the `template.mustache` included and your exact `Gruntfile.js`, still worked for me… I think you should check in some very basic, vanilla setup, if the `watch` task would work for you at all.